# Symfony2 :500 Internal error on assetic generated file in dev mode

Tags: symfony, assetic

I use assetic on my Symfony2 project and when i put my project on a new server environement i have the following 500 internal Server Error on the top of the CSS and JS generated files on dev environement. It seems that assetic can't access to the temp directory to generate the file.

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | ErrorException
[message] Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/jo/Developpement/coV2/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/Yui/BaseCompressorFilter.php line 92
[1] ErrorException: Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/jo/Developpement/coV2/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/Yui/BaseCompressorFilter.php line 92
                at n/a
                    in /Users/jo/Developpement/coV2/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/Yui/BaseCompressorFilter.php line 92

                at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty', '/Users/jo/Developpement/coV2/Symfony/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/Yui/BaseCompressorFilter.php', '92', array('content' => '/*!
```

The line 92 of the BaseCompressorFilter class is the last line of this code :

```
    $tempDir = realpath(sys_get_temp_dir());
    $input = tempnam($tempDir, 'YUI-IN-');
    $output = tempnam($tempDir, 'YUI-OUT-');
    file_put_contents($input, $content);
```

$tempDir is ok, but $input is empty.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you check the return value of sys_get_temp_dir() and the permissions of this directory?

Comment: Yes, the directory is an existing directory with all privileges.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem on dev environment